# What did "John Boy" mean (as an insult) in New Zealand around 1977?

Tags: pejorative-language, new-zealand-english

According to the [records](https://www.parliament.nz/en/visit-and-learn/history-and-buildings/special-topics/unparliamentary-language/) of the New Zealand Parliament, "John Boy" was considered  unparliamentary language in 1977. What did the phrase mean though, back then, over there? Urban dictionary [seems](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=John%20boy) say it could be either a derogatory term for "white guy" or one for homosexual. I'm guessing it was probably the latter in 1977, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Was the US TV show "[The Waltons](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068149/)" aired in NZ?

Comment: Might be from the American TV series *The Waltons*, which had a character named John-Boy, but that doesn't seem particularly pejorative.

Comment: @Robusto - I used to hear "John-Boy" used as a mild pejorative in the US.  Kind of a doofus.

Comment: @HotLicks: that sounds a bit more plausible (than what urban dictionary proposes), given the parliamentary context.